# How to reference jars in Maven that are not hosted on mvnrepo but Eclipse Orbit?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I have a Maven based Java project, which has a dependency on an Eclipse project (as an external jar). To build my project, I installed this jar to my local repo as it is not found in the public mvnrepo and I created a pom file for that external jar, like:

```
<groupId>org.eclipse.someproject</groupId>
<artifactId>somemodule</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

However, it wasn't enough as it seems the external jar also depends on some other libraries. After a lot of searching I could found those jars in one of the Eclipse Orbit scm (I may not get the terms right). Again, none of them could be found on the public mvnrepo.

I wonder if there is a way to include these jars as dependencies in the pom file that I have created for the external jar, so that Maven can grab them for me? Without having to download each one of them and then install them to my local repo?

More specifically, I am after some settings in pom to allow accessing the Eclipse scm and grab those jars as dependencies.

Comment: Is there a reason not to put the *actual* group and artifact IDs in the question?

Comment: I would try to figure out if there is any Maven repository that hosts the jar you need. Then you can add that Maven repository to your `<repositories>` list in your `settings.xml` or your `pom.xml` and everything works without manually downloading and installing jars.